# Is there a way to migrate a repository from Team Coherence to either Team Foundation Server or Git?

Tags: git, tfs, migration, repository

Currently using Team Coherence for repository. I need to migrate this to either Team Foundation Server (TFS) or Git. Are there any built in tools that can accomplish this? Eclipse plugin? Or some software that can be purchased to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look to this project to migrate to a local git repository:

https://github.com/frogonwheels/TC2Git

Once it's done, that's easy to push it to the git provider you want (TFS or another)...

Comment: Great thank you. Looks like this should solve my problem.